# how to search through pointers

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a program in which there is a function to like the posts other users have posted.
I have to search through all the users who have already liked the post to see if the current user using the app has already liked the post or not.
if not, then the number of likes must be increased by 1 and also the user be stored among the likers so they can't like this post more than once.
The  problem is that I don't know how to search through the likers to find out if the user have already liked the post or not.

```
typedef struct user user;
struct user{
    char* userName;
    char* password;
    user* next;
};
typedef struct message message;
struct message{
    char* content;
    user* owner;
    user** likers;
    int likes;
    int postID;
    message* next;
};
int postLiking(user* owner, user* liker, int postID,message* dummyMessage){
    /*dummyMessage is the first message node*/
    while(dummyMessage!=NULL){
        if(dummyMessage->owner==owner){
            if(dummyMessage->postID==postID){
                /*must check if the liker has liked to post or not;if not, add them to the likers and increase the likes by 1*/
                //return 1;
            }
            else{
                printf("the user doesn't have a post with this post ID");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

edited:I have this other idea:

```
typedef struct message message;
struct message{
    char* content;
    user* owner;
    int likes;
    int postID;
    message* next;
    likers* head;
};
typedef likers likers;
struct likers{
    char* liker;
    likers* next;
};
```

edited: but I'[m not sure how to use it to search through the likers yet.

my idea was to save the likers as double pointers as you can see above. but I don't know how to search through them.
also I don't know if there are any better ways to save the likers.
I'll be glad if you help.
or maybe I have to kind of make a linked list within a linked list?

Comment: You cannot save the likers *as* double pointers.  You can, however, use double pointers to *point to* dynamically-sized arrays of pointers to likers.  This is a crucial distinction, because the mechanism for searching the data structure is a function of the data structure, not (directly) of the means by which you *access* the data structure.

Comment: Have you tried simpler exercises first, such as iterating through an array of `int`?

Comment: @beta yes I have, but for my assignment I have to do this one.

Comment: Your `postLiking()` function appears to be set up (incompletely) to search messages for those liked by a given user, but that's not what you say you actually want to do.  You already know -- or should know -- which message to check.  What you want to search is that message's current list if likers.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes I know which message to check but I don't know how to check

Comment: If you say so.  My point is that you don't appear even to be trying to check the right thing.

Comment: I presume that `likers` points to the beginning of an array of `user*`. Do you know how to iterate through that array?

Comment: Please show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your program, with the code that establishes these data structures, and the input used to do so (or hardcode it). Please show the *specific* implementation that you are currently working on and having problems with, not tentative code for a different implementation. This should be solvable with a simple [linear search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search) but, as pointed out, the signature of `postLiking` does not make much sense, and the current example lacks context.